# How can I make update-manager require less free disk space on root partition

Tags: filesystem, update-manager, disk-usage, 14.10

My system contains a relatively small root partion (around 16) and the rest on home. Now my upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 fails because it needs 8 GB of free space on root but I only have 4 GB and I see no trivial way to reduce it.

I've tried relinking /var/cache/apt/archives to a directory under home but with no effect. It seem like the Ubuntu installer looks at the amount of free space on root regardless. Do I have to revert to a fresh install?

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF
NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $ADDKERNEL |grep -vE $METAKERNEL|grep -v $NEWKERNEL)
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS
update-manager -d
```

Software Updater will show up and search for the new release, after a few seconds, you will see a screen that saying:

However, Ubuntu 14.10 is available now.

Press the button Upgrade to start upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10.

The Software Updater will ask you to confirm still you want to upgrade, press Start Upgrade to begin installing Ubuntu 14.10.

Now, the Software Updater will prepare to start setting up new software channels, and after a few minutes, the software updater will notify you the details the number of packages are going to be removed, and number of packages are going to be installed, press Start upgrade to continue.

Comment: Great tips, but my root is still too small; 6.2 GB when update-manager needs around 8 GB. Seems like a really dumb limitation. I guess I have to do a clean install.

Comment: I managed to remove some waste to make update-manager happy. BTW: is there a completely automatic alternative to update-manager that doesn't require any midway user interactions?

Comment: Search the disk directories obsolete. Empty the trash. Move /opt to /home simply copying. If this is not enough to move /usr to /home (more complicated). I installed in /opt, Firefox, Apache OpenOffice, ClipGrab and MasterpdfEditor and only use 7.7 gigs of /

Comment: I do not know is there a completely automatic alternative to update-manager. I am a person who prefers to interact from the console

Comment: @Nordlöw - rather then a fresh install, I advise you resize your partitions and give / more space.